# linear regression model with AR errors python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Is there a python package (statsmodels/scipy/pandas/etc...) with functionality for estimating coefficients for a linear regression model with autoregressive errors in python, such as the following SAS implementation below? http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_autoreg_sect003.htm

Answer (score 5):

statsmodels http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/index.html has ARMA, ARIMA and SARIMAX models that take explanatory variables to model the mean. This corresponds to a linear model, `y = X b + e`, where the error term e follows an ARMA or seasonal ARMA process. AR errors are a special case when the moving average term has no lags.

statsmodels also has an autoregressive AR class but it does not allow for explanatory variables.

In these time series models, prediction is a conditional prediction that takes the history into account for forecasting.

statsmodels also has a GLSAR class which is a linear model that removes the effect of autocorrelated AR residuals. This uses feasible generalized least squares estimation and can only predict the unconditional term `X b`.

http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA

http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/statespace.html#seasonal-autoregressive-integrated-moving-average-with-exogenous-regressors-sarimax

Comment: ARIMA/ARMA/SARIMAX are not what i'm looking for.  i want a model with autoregressive error terms, not autoregressive independent/dependent variables.  The GLSAR from statsmodels does not properly predict out of sample since it does not take the auto regressive error term into account

Comment: @asdf ARIMA/ARMA/SARIMAX  are linear regression models with serially correlated errors if there are explanatory variables (`X`), exactly the same as GLSAR but using MLE. Check the two possible specification of ARMAX eg. by Hyndman.

Comment: I think the problem with using ARIMA family models for this intended purpose is that they don't give you the ability to include random effects terms.