# linear regression model with ARMA/ARIMA in python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Can someone give me a basic example of how to use an ARMA combined with a linear regression? I have an independent variable X that I want to regress to Y but using AR on X.  Any simple example would be super helpful.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555958/linear-regression-model-with-ar-errors-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick set up to get you started

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import ARMA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(500), index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=500))

p, q = 1, 1

arma = ARMA(endog=ts, order=(p, q)).fit()

print arma.summary()

                              ARMA Model Results                              
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                  500
Model:                     ARMA(1, 1)   Log Likelihood                -678.805
Method:                       css-mle   S.D. of innovations              0.941
Date:                Tue, 17 May 2016   AIC                           1365.610
Time:                        00:01:52   BIC                           1382.469
Sample:                    01-01-2010   HQIC                          1372.225
                         - 05-15-2011                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0624      0.048      1.311      0.191        -0.031     0.156
ar.L1.y        0.3090      0.311      0.992      0.322        -0.302     0.919
ma.L1.y       -0.2177      0.318     -0.684      0.494        -0.841     0.406
                                    Roots                                    
=============================================================================
                 Real           Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AR.1            3.2367           +0.0000j            3.2367            0.0000
MA.1            4.5939           +0.0000j            4.5939            0.0000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you! if I wanted to not use a time series but some other dataset (say SPY price to VIX price), would I use the same set up?

Comment: ARMA is a timeseries tool.  Autoregressive Moving Average is all about comparing a current value (in time) to previous values (in time).  You seem to be referring to an ols regression.

Comment: Appreciate the help! thought there was combination of the two? Using my previous example - say I wanted the ARMA for an independent variable (SPY and its previous values) to help build the regression for a dependent variable. Something similar to this [link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/74)